# Ordered set - Up-set

Tags: lattice-orders, characteristic-functions

I understand the definition of characteristic function and order-preserving, but I don't know how to prove the exercise.

**Definition**. We write $\mathbf{2}$ to denote the chain obtened by giving $P$ the order in which $0 < 1 < 2$.

> Prove that a subset $U$ of an ordered set $P$ is an up-set if and only if its characteristic function $\mathscr{X}_U : P \rightarrow \mathbf{2}$ is order-preserving. (Here $\mathscr{X}_U (x) = 1$ if $x \in U$ and $\mathscr{X}_U (x) = 0$ if $x \notin U$.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

For a function $f:P\to \{0<1\}$ to be order-preserving is equivalent to the statement

if $f(x)=1$ and $x<y$ then $f(y)=1$

which is the same as

if $x\in f^{-1}(1)$ and $x<y$ then $y\in f^{-1}(1)$

which is the same as that $f^{-1}(1)$ is an up-set.

(Your definition of 2 is confusing, normally 2 denotes the order $\{0<1\}$.)